# If A is a subtype of B, is (A→B) → A a subtype of (B→B) → A?

Tags: subtyping

Assume that A is a subtype of  B,
Is(A→B)→A a subtype of(B→B)→A?
Is A→(B→A)a subtype of B→(B→A)?

Comment: what does this symbolism mean (A→B)→A ? Can you explain

Comment: A→B means giving input of type A and producing output of type B

Comment: Yes, some context would help to understand what it is that you're asking. Also this looks like you just pasted some assignment given to you. It would look better if you gave us your answer and reasoning, we can check whether you are correct.

Comment: First, it is not my assignment. Just random question I found on internet since Im studying subtyping. And I posted it cuz i dont know the answer...

Comment: How would you go about figuring out the answer? If you have no idea where to even start, you may have to study harder...

Comment: Yeah, I think that this question is still pretty hard to parse.  Can you give an example in a specific programming language, which would make it more appropriate for this site?  Otherwise perhaps you need the theoretical CS stack exchange site.

Comment: I think this is about function types. The notation looks a bit like something from functional languages with currying.

Comment: if this is what the symbolism means (havent seen it before regarding object-oriented programming) Then what does `X being a subtype of Y` means?  if you answer that, then you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: for example see [Function types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Function_types)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Subtypes and Function Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Function_types) an approach would be the following:

**Symbolism and hypothesis:**

1. `A` is **subtype** of `B` (`A < B`)
2. `X→Y` is a function (type) that receives instances of type `X` and returns instances of type `Y`
3. A function type `S1→S2` is a **subtype** of `T1→T2` **iif** `T1 < S1` **and** `S2 < T2`

For `(A→B)→A` to be a subtype of `(B→B)→A` it would be needed:

1. `(B→B)` < `(A→B)` and
2. `A < A` (true by identity)

For `(B→B) < (A→B)` to hold again applying function subtypes we need:

1. `A < B` (true by hypothesis) and
2. `B < B` (true by indentity)

So `(A→B)→A` is a subtype of `(B→B)→A` or `(A→B)→A < (B→B)→A`

Try to follow similar analysis to answer second question:

Is `A→(B→A)` a subtype of `B→(B→A)`?